# Sorting Array objects based on Time property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-apps-script

I have two arrays and I need to convert them into array object. Data array at the end is the array object after I push two arrays into one array object.
Now I need to sort them based on time. I am new to js so that I would like to ask for a solution or pseudo code for this problem.

```
var arrayMachineName = ['V0101', 'V0103', 'V0102', 'V0201', 'V0202', 'V1101', 'V1202', 'V0503', 'V1102', 'V1601', 'V0602', 'V1201', 'V1702'];
var outOfResinTimeArray = ['19:20', '17:30', '13:20', '12:30', '21:20', '12:30', '03:30', '07:20', '04:30', '21:20', '22:30', '16:20', '14:30'];

function outOfResinTimeSorting(arrayMachineName, outOfResinTimeArray) {
    var cellOneToSixdataObj = [];
    var cellSevenToTwelvedataObj = [];
    var cellThirdTeenToSevenTeendataObj = [];
    for (var machineCounter = 0; machineCounter < arrayMachineName.length; machineCounter++) {
        var machineCode = parseInt(arrayMachineName[machineCounter].slice(1,3));
        if (machineCode >= 1 && machineCode <= 6) { 
            cellOneToSixdataObj.push({machine: arrayMachineName[machineCounter], time: outOfResinTimeArray[machineCounter]});
        }   
        else if (machineCode > 6 && machineCode <= 12) { 
            cellSevenToTwelvedataObj.push({machine: arrayMachineName[machineCounter], time: outOfResinTimeArray[machineCounter]});
        }
        else if (machineCode > 12 && machineCode <= 17) {
            cellThirdTeenToSevenTeendataObj.push({machine: arrayMachineName[machineCounter], time: outOfResinTimeArray[machineCounter]});
            }
        }
    console.log(cellOneToSixdataObj);
    console.log(cellSevenToTwelvedataObj);
    console.log(cellThirdTeenToSevenTeendataObj);
    var sortable = [];
    for (var machine in cellOneToSixdataObj){
        sortable.push([machine, cellOneToSixdataObj[machine]]);
    }
}

outOfResinTimeSorting(arrayMachineName, outOfResinTimeArray);


var Data =[
    { machine: 'V0101', time: '19:20' },
    { machine: 'V0103', time: '17:30' },
    { machine: 'V0102', time: '13:20' },
    { machine: 'V0201', time: '12:30' },
    { machine: 'V0202', time: '21:20' },
    { machine: 'V0503', time: '07:20' },
    { machine: 'V0602', time: '22:30' }
];
```

Comment: MDN is one of the wonderful JS resources. read array.sort function from there will be better than use any answer from here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I am aware of reading JS documentation is very important before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a standard javascript `Array.prototype.sort()` method  with `localeCompare`

```
Data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.time.localeCompare(b.time);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 0):

Make an iteration over `machineName` using [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) array and create the object. After formatting your expected data, sort the array based on time.

```js
var arrayMachineName = ['V0101', 'V0103', 'V0102', 'V0201', 'V0202', 'V1101', 'V1202', 'V0503', 'V1102', 'V1601', 'V0602', 'V1201', 'V1702'];
var outOfResinTimeArray = ['19:20', '17:30', '13:20', '12:30', '21:20', '12:30', '03:30', '07:20', '04:30', '21:20', '22:30', '16:20', '14:30'];

// Format data array
var data = arrayMachineName.map(function(m, i) {
    return {machine: m, time: outOfResinTimeArray[i]};
});

// Sort data array base on time
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return Number(a.time.replace(':', '')) < Number(b.time.replace(':', '')) ? -1 : 1
});

console.log(data);
```